# get current Url in codedUI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using CodedUI to automate my site .How will i get the current url .
i am launching http://example.com ,but later in  my application i am appending E=U and E=P to it bases on some conditions .I want to know how to identify if E=U /E=p ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch();
//Some Code Here
Uri uri = browser.Uri;
string st = uri.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch();
        //Some Code Here
        string st = browser.Uri.ToString();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The address bar of the browser contains the URL and its contents can be accessed in at least two ways:

1. By accessing the value of the field in the same fashion as would be done by a Coded UI assertion generated by the recorder.
2. By selecting the text and copying it into the clipboard. Click in the address bar, send Control-A and a Control-C characters, then just use the clipboard contents.